# Using MergJSON to move data from a data grid to a Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, livecode

After I successfully implemented the retrieval of documents from my local mongo server, I began trying the opposite, sending data stored in a data grid (DG) to the server,  so I created a card with:

- a DG (DG_02) with two columns, _id and Nombre, a field (E),
- a script with a mouseup handler,

that:

```
put the dgData of DG_02 into pArray2

puts the 5th element of pArray2,into pArray,
```

(I just want to try this with only one element for now)

```
sets pForceRootType,pPretty parameters for the MergJSON function
```

call the function ArrayToJSON

```
put tJSON in fiel "E" to see what the function is returning
```

Construct the string for use with the shell command

```
put the result in rmongo to see the server answer
```

The whole script

```
on mouseUp

 local dbText
 put the dgData of grp "DG_02" into  pArray2
 put pArray2[5] into pArray   <-- Only the 5th element of the array
 put "string" into tipo
 put "false" into bonito
 put ArrayToJSON(pArray, tipo, bonito) into tJSON
 put tJSON into fld "E"
 put "db.nueva.insert("& tJSON & ");" into dbText

 put shell("C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe --eval" && "'" & dbText & "'" ) into rmongo

 put rmongo

end mouseUp
```

These are my observations when executing the script, modifying the parameter pForceRootType for the function:

When tipo is set to Object field "E" gets: {"Nombre":"Sofia","_id":1012}

When tipo is set to String, field "E" gets: {"Nombre":"Sofia","_id":"001012"}

In both cases (tipo = string or tipo = object) rmongo, show this in the message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.7

connecting to: test

db.nueva.insert({Nombre:Sofia,_id:001012});
```

The document is not inserted.

When trying the insert directly in the shell, I can see that in order to do a successful insert, the string values should be quoted, but (if I am not wrong in my observations) the JSON returned by the function does not quote the strings.

I will appreciate your guide with this, thank you in advance, Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returned by ArrayToJSON has appropriate quotes as you can see in the text of field "E".

My best guess is you need to escape the strings for the shell call so try:

```
replace quote with "^"&quote in tJSON
```

Of course then it's no longer safe to have a quote in any of your strings.

Comment: Just want to thank for editing my post,Hannes. I'll try to be more careful formating my posts.  Monte, thank you for your help.

Comment: You are welcome, may I ask you to add an explanation what the variables are for?

Comment: Hannes, the variables bonito and tipo, are arguments for the MergJSON function that returns a JSON from an Array. Are you asking for the purpose of these?